# How to add text over an image that "falls off" the image

Tags: html, css

So I spent a couple hours searching, but all I've seeing is just standard help with adding text over an image, nothing that will put the text over the image, as it "falls" off the image.

I've attached an example of what I'm referring to.

I'm trying to do it in a way so the images stay right under each other and not create space between the, added another photo for reference on what I mean.

I've tried creating an img-container and add text but that doesn't allow me to have the text "fall" off the image. This is what I have so far (not including the text".

I've attempted to make the images as the body background but that didn't have the same design I'm looking for unfortunately, as the text will also serve as links in the future.

[images stacked with no space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aflgd.jpg)

[text falling off the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkULH.jpg)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="navigation.css">
  <title>Pasetta Studios</title>
</head>
  <body>

<div id="wrapper">
        <div class="navbar">
          <a href="#index.html">Home</a>
          <a href="#about.html">About</a>
          <a href="#projects.html">Projects</a>
          <a href="#contact.html">Contact</a>
       </div>

      <div class="img-container">
        <img src="images/top-image.jpg" alt="plants">
        <img src="images/second-image.jpg" alt="benches">
        <img src="images/third-image.jpg" alt="cactus">
        <img src="images/last-image.jpg" alt="more cactus">
        <img src="images/pasetta-studios" alt="pasetta studios">
      </div>





        <code>Designed by @PasettaStudios. </code>





   </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

And here is my CSS

```
@font-face {
    src: url(fonts/Modric.ttf);
    font-family: Modric;
}

@font-face {
    src: url(fonts/Orkney-Regular.ttf);
    font-family: Orkney;
}

@font-face {
    src: url(fonts/Made-Bon-Voyage.otf);
    font-family: Made-Bon-Voyage;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#wrapper {
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-left: 50px;
}

body {
  background-color: #262c2c;
}

.navbar {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;

}

/* links and text inside nav bar */
.navbar a {
  float: left;
  padding: 40px 0px 0px 0px;
  background-color: #262c2c;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 25%; /* Four links of equal widths */
  text-align: center;
  color: #dae1e7;
  font-family: Orkney;

}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Orkney;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    opacity: 50%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

}

p {
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 100px;
    padding-left: 100px;
    color: #dae1e7;
    font-family: Modric;
    font-size: 150px;
}
```

Comment: I'm not fully understand what you want :) do you want to text fall off or no??

Comment: I do, I haven't been able to find a way to do. I've tried the img-container method but for some version it did not work. So I'm reviewing my work to make sure I'm not completely botching it. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is put your Image in a Container, along with your text. The text is then positioned absolute and with a negative margin or left and right values instead of only setting top values.

```
<div class="img-container">
    <img src="img1.jpg" alt="Image 1">
    <p class="lefttext">Left</p>
    <p class="righttext">Right</p>
</div>

<div class="img-container">
    <img src="img2.jpg" alt="Image 2">
    <p class="lefttext">Left</p>
    <p class="righttext">Right</p>
</div>
```

For multiple images, just repeat this code.

And your CSS:

```
.img-container {
    position:relative;
    margin:0;
    padding:0 40px;
}

.img-container img {
    border:0;
}

.img-container p.lefttext {
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    margin-left:-40px;
}

.img-container p.righttext {
    position:absolute;
    top:120px;
    width:100%;
    text-align:right;
    margin-right:—40px;
}
```

Alternatively, you could do

```
.img-container p.lefttext {
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:0;
}

.img-container p.righttext {
    position:absolute;
    top:120px;
    text-align:right;
    right:0;
}
```

If the position of the text over the image should change for each picture, simply remove the ˋtop:..pxˋ from your CSS and add ˋstyle="top:50px;"ˋ to each image tag.

Comment: Ah yes, in the CSS, I had leftalign and rightalign instead of lefttext and righttext

Comment: yup, I saw that and fixed it but still did not work. I'm trying other means right now. I really do appreciate your help

Comment: I‘m sorry. What happens when you answer coding questions on your phone is that you forget half the lines. I’ve edited it and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<div class="img-container">
    <div class="row">
      <img src="images/top-image.jpg" alt="plants">
      <span>Your text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <img src="images/second-image.jpg" alt="benches">
      <span>Your text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <img src="images/third-image.jpg" alt="cactus">
      <span>Your text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <img src="images/last-image.jpg" alt="more cactus">
      <span>Your text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <img src="images/pasetta-studios" alt="pasetta studios">
      <span>Your text</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.img-container {
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
}

.row{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.row span {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  top: 0;
}

.row:nth-child(odd) span {
  left: -20px;
}

.row:nth-child(even) span {
  right: -20px;
}
```